# Masculine or feminine

Tags: género

In the sentence " all of the region is surrounded by green areas/zones...",
should it be  ..?

Todo la región está rodeado de zonas verdes
o "Toda la región está rodeada de zonas verdes

Thank you

Comment: The [dictionary](https://dle.rae.es/regi%C3%B3n) says it's feminine, like most words ending in -ión.

Answer (score 4):

"Toda la región está rodeada de áreas/zonas verdes"

The article in the phrase is "la", feminine. Hence, that implies that the word "región" is feminine. That forces the first word (Todo/Toda) to be feminine as well.

If you look for "el región" in google, you won't find anything. While "la región" will show more results.

The comment in the question is wrong, not all words with "ión" are feminine "camión", is masculine.

Comment: The comment says *most* not *all*

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought. I read something online that had  it as"Todo  la región" but it must be a misprint.